# React conditional to check if my api calls have an error and abort all if one of them has an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, conditional-statements

I want to check if any one of my three api calls has an error and if so, abort all of them. So far, I've managed to only get the functions to check if they're fired but I realize that I'm only checking this regardless of errors. So do I have to put the conditional in my actual api call functions or can i do it outside the scope? BTW, I have put all three functions in one function, as they all fire together in an async manner onClick button. heres my code.

```
async fetchData() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('api/.../...');
        this.setState({
            locationFull: res.data,
            sent: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({
            error,
            sent: false
        });
        console.log('Data not got');
    }
};


async sendData() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('api/.../...');
        this.setState({
            locationFull: res.data,
            sent: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({
            error,
            sent: false
        });
        console.log('data not sent');
    }
};


async updateData() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.put('api/.../...');
        this.setState({
            locationFull: res.data,
            sent: true
        });
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({
            error,
            sent: false
        });
        console.log('data not updated');
    }
};
```

my combined function that fires all three

```
async combinedFunction() { 
await this.fetchData();
await this.sendData();
await this.updateData();
await this.sentCheck();
};
```

my conditional to check for errors (which i know is wrong but its what i have so far)

```
sentCheck() {
const fetched =  this.fetchData;
const updated=  this.updateData;
const sent =  this.sendData;
if (!fetched) {
    console.log('error in fetching');
} else if (!updated) {
    console.log('error in updating');   
} else if (!sent) {
    console.log('error in sent');   
}
};
```

So again, I want to ultimately cancel all calls if one of the three calls fires an error (as they update and post to different endpoints and collections in the back-end).

Comment: How are you expected to abort something that's already completed?, your `combinedFunction` will abort as soon as it hits an error,.. eg. If `fetchData` was ok but `sendData` failed, you can't now abort `fetchData` it's already done.

Comment: Also,  if you ever catch an error, don't forget to re-throw.  `catch (error) { /*do something*/; throw error; }`  Otherwise all promises will execute regardless..

Comment: Hi Keith, I realised the code I had was bogus but I just wanted to put it out there and you're throw suggestion works great for a single case. thank you for that. going to now try @Martin's suggestion.

Comment: edit - @Martin's code did the same thing as the throw error does. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()`.
As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all),

> If any of the passed-in promises reject, Promise.all asynchronously
>   rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, whether or not
>   the other promises have resolved.

```
const fetchData = axios.get('api/.../...');
const sendData = axios.post('api/.../...');
const updateData = axios.put('api/.../...');

Promise.all([fetchData , sendData , updateData ]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Hi Martin, unfortunately that code didn't work. When I error test e.g. sendData with the wrong api uri, then the console.log(values) returns fetchData and updateData as Accepted promises but rejects the sendData promise. I need them all to be rejected if one is rejected. All for one and one for all sort of thing.